# Using crosswalk Launch Screen feature in an cordova/ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [Launch Screen](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest/launch_screen.html) feature of crosswalk in a cordova/ionic app.

The crosswalk configuration go into config.xml (stuff like xwalkMode and xwalkVersion) but looks like the launch screen should go in the manifest that is loaded from the activity.

Appreciate any guidance on the issue.

Comment: i need it @haki, have you solved this?

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet.